Background Location - EXPO React Native don't work
I have an app developed by me. The app needs send the device coordinates to backend.  I am use expo-location to do this.
I make the foreground getter with this code and works:
foregroundSubscription = await Location.watchPositionAsync(
  {
    accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
    distanceInterval: FIFTY_METERS,
    // distanceInterval: 1,
    timeInterval: FIVE_SECONDS, // ONLY ANDROID
  },

But in background, the background api expo don't get the coordinates:

TaskManager.defineTask(
  BACKGROUND_LOCATION_TASK_KEY,
  ({
    data: { locations },
    error,
  }: {
    data: { locations: Location.LocationObject[] };
    error: any;
  }) => {
    const locationsBackground: Location.LocationObject[] =
      locations as Location.LocationObject[];

    const coordinates: Coordinate[] = [];
  [... rest of code inside taskManager]
}

export function LocationContextProvider({children}: Props) {
  [...rest of code]

async function backgroundWatcher() {
    console.log('BACKGROUND_INIT');
    const isTaskDefined = await TaskManager.isTaskDefined(
      BACKGROUND_LOCATION_TASK_KEY,
    );

    if (!isTaskDefined) {
      return;
    }

    const hasStarted = await Location.hasStartedLocationUpdatesAsync(
      BACKGROUND_LOCATION_TASK_KEY,
    );

    if (hasStarted) {
      await Location.stopLocationUpdatesAsync(BACKGROUND_LOCATION_TASK_KEY);
    }

    console.log('INIT_SERVICE_BACKGROUND');

    await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(BACKGROUND_LOCATION_TASK_KEY, {
      accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
      activityType: Location.ActivityType.AutomotiveNavigation,
      showsBackgroundLocationIndicator: true,
      distanceInterval: FIFTY_METERS,
      // distanceInterval: 1,
      timeInterval: FIVE_SECONDS, // ONLY ANDROID
      foregroundService: {
        notificationTitle: 'TOT Agendamento',
        notificationBody: 'Operação em andamento',
        notificationColor: '#fff',
      },
    });
  }

I need when the app running in the background mode, the background works. I see in a github issue the code I wrote not work on expo go app, only works in a build app. I tested in APK but don't work too. Try I'm waiting the google analysis to send the app to play store and test in app build .aab
But I have a lot of doubts about this. Can you help me?
